# Volume knob on guitar has no effect when rolled

Tags: electric-guitar, electronics

I have a problem with my Yamaha SG copy guitar.

The volume knobs are not effective. At 1 it's at its peak and rolling it up to 10 does nothing — it's more like an on/off switch.

I am in Nigeria with no luthier here.

Please if you can tell me, I have basic knowledge on soldering. I can take pictures and you can help me thanks.

Comment: Seem like something inside has shorted - maybe because the part under the knob is loose? Take the cover off from the back, and post some pics.

Answer (score 1):

If the volume knob is basically only working in an on/off manner, this usually means that the track of the volume pot is broken (when the wiper crosses the break, it works like an on/off switch).  You'd need to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

The potentiometer may have moisture in it, or have become tarnished and be shorting out. A silicone based electrical lubricant spray inside the potentiometer could help to displace the moisture.

If the tone knob works normally, you could try swapping the volume and tone potentiometers to see if it is the pot itself, or something else. If it is the pot, your best option would probably be to replace it.